# WebElement location not matching expected values from window().getSize()

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, mocha.js

I am testing that a bar is correctly fixed at the bottom of the screen by testing that it is positioned at `window().getSize().height()` - `bar.height`. The code looks like this (I'm using the Nemo Selenium wrapper)

```
nemo.view._waitVisible('id:my-id').getLocation().then(pos => {
  nemo.driver.manage().window().getSize().then(wSize => {
    pos.y.should.equal(wSize.height - 75);
  })
})
```

where 75 is the height of my bar. However, when I run this I'm getting that `pos.y` is 886, but `wSize.height` - 75 is 980. I can definitely verify that the bar is located where it's supposed to be when the Selenium Firefox window opens, so I'm guessing that the values of `window().getSize()` and/or `getLocation()` aren't returning exactly what I think they do, and I can't seem to find documentation on it.

This is using Javascript, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`getSize()` returns `org.openqa.selenium.Dimension` object while `getLocation()` returns `org.openqa.selenium.Point` object. The documentation for both is available in official Selenium Github [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/overview-summary.html).

`Dimension` object holds `width` and `height` properties and `Point` object encapsulates x,y coordinates.

Comment: This question concerns Javascript, not Java.

Comment: @Weston I believe that the objects still hold the same information though.

Comment: Either way, that is what I'm expecting them to return. The y position of the bar should be the height of the window (`wSize.height`) minus the height of the bar (75).